# Subtuples of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

How do I generate

```
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (0,1,2)]
```

programmatically (that is, without writing everything out by hand)? That is, a list of all nonempty subtuples of the tuple `(0,1,2)`.

(Note this is not asking for sub*sets* but sub*tuples*.)

Comment: It *is* asking for subsets, specifically non-empty ones that are ordered as a subsequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> t = (0, 1, 2)
>>> print [subset for r in range(1,4) for subset in itertools.combinations(t,r)]
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Itertools is a powerful resource. You should check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `powerset()` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) and remove the empty set:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

as follows:

```
In [3]: [ss for ss in powerset([0,1,2]) if ss]
Out[3]: [(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: Aside from any details regarding order, I need usually the powerset without the empty set and without the full set - so I use the `recipe` above but use `range(1,len(s))` - not sure it is bulletproof...

Comment: @nate I think this is safe: letting `r` range between `1` and `n-1` inclusive omits the empty set and the full set from the call to `combinations`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is basically powerset but without the empty set.  By modifying the recipe from the [python itertools page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to start with a combinations size of `1`:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def almost_powerset(seq):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(seq, r) 
                for r in range(1, len(seq)+1)))
```

and then just pass in your sequence

```
lst = [0, 1, 2]
res = almost_powerset(lst)
```

This generates all the combinations of size 1, then size 2, etc, up to the total length of your sequence, then uses `chain` to connect them.